# Storing object using ArrayList and test with main method

Tags: java, oop, object, arraylist

I am a java beginner and trying to teach myself ArrayList. I intend to write a program to store bank class that consists of a list of bank accounts which include: name,balance and account number. I also want to test the Bank class with main()method to retrieval an account or removal a account through account number.

here is what I have done so far:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class W7E1b {
    public static void main(String[]args) {

        ArrayList <BankAccount> accountList = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

        accountList.add(new BankAccount("Peter",100.00));
        accountList.add(new BankAccount("Jan",1500.00));

        BankAccount.setName("Phil");
        System.out.println(accountList.get(1).getName());
    }

    public class BankAccount {
        private String Name;
        private double balance;
        private static int accountNum;
        private static int lastAccountNum = 0;

        public BankAccount(String Name, double balance) {
            this.Name = Name;
            this.balance = balance;
            lastAccountNum++;
            accountNum = lastAccountNum;
        }


        public void setName(String nm) {
            Name = nm;
        }
        public void setbalance(double bl) {
            balance =bl;
        }
        public int getaccountNum() {
            return accountNum;
        }

    }
}
```

It shows error in the main method when I try to add parameter to the object using add method in ArrayList. I am confused by the ArrayList concept now. 
I don't get where I have done wrong in the code.

Should I still declare a constructor if i want to use ArrayList to store object? if there are multiple object with the same kind of parameters, can I create only one constructor or multiple? Where should I declare the Arraylist?

if anyone could help me with my other questions about the OOPs concept would be great: if there are multiple object with the same kind of parameters, can I create only one constructor or multiple?

Comment: Why are `accountNum` and `lastAccountNum` static? Don't you need to create an object before doing this `BankAccount.setName("Phil");` as `setName(String nm) is *not* static.

Comment: 2 compilation problems here: You must call `setName("Phil")` on `BankAccount` *instance* (the one that you want changed), and you didn't define a `getName` method in `BankAccount`.

Comment: because once an obejct is created, i want an account Number can be assigned to the object. like account.1, account.2, account.3 ect

Comment: So why static? Its should be non-static, so that *each* object is associated with an *accountNumber*, instead of *sharing* one static member across all objects of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all there is a compilation error in the  `BankAccount.setName("Phil");`. `SetName()` is a instance method and require an object to access and cannot be accessed by className.

Also, constructor can be used as in your case. Otherwise you may have to declare other method to set all instance variables which is what constructor is doing and is preferable or different methods for each instance variable(not required).

For multiple objects with same kind of parameters you require one constructor only.

Also, you have declared ArrayList after which you are adding the objects of  `BankAccount`  type which seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of ArrayList is correct.

```
ArrayList <BankAccount> accountList = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
```

Here you are declaring that your accountList will contain objects of type Bank Account.

```
accountList.add(new BankAccount("Peter",100.00));
accountList.add(new BankAccount("Jan",1500.00));
```

Here code is doing 2 things, creating Object of type BankAccount using constructor you've provided and adding these newly created objects to the accountList.

Your code seem to have compilation issue on following 2 lines:-

```
BankAccount.setName("Phil");
System.out.println(accountList.get(1).getName());
```

On First line, you are trying to invoke setName() method on class(as if It is a static method), while in BankAccount class it is specified as instance method. (without static keyword)

On Second line, you are retrieving object of BookAccount class with `accountList.get(1)` and then invoke a getName() method on it. However, getName() is not present in your BookAccount class.

Based on the code i see, your understanding of ArrayList seems fine.